# jQuery create a real-time array from multiple inputs with the same class

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, class

I have multiple inputs on a page that all have the same class name `authority-email`. Using jQuery I get the values from all the inputs using the following:

```
var emailObj = {};
$("input[class=authority-email]").each(function () {
  var email = $(this).val()

  emailObj = email;

  console.log(emailObj);
});
```

These inputs can be removed and added to the DOM using jQuery. The values within the inputs are also editable.

As the input changes (remove, add, edit) What is the best way to pass their values in real-time to my `emailObj`?

Comment: Pro tip: use `'input.authority-email'` as the selector.

Comment: Are you going to send those input values to the server at some point? Perhaps `.serialize()` on the form element would be a good idea then.

Comment: Yep. I'm passing the values to a hidden field that requires a weird pg format `.serialize()` isn't required in this instance but thanks for the recommendation!

Comment: It should really be the job of the backend to format it properly to be used in PG.

Comment: I agree completely @Ja͢ck but it can't be helped in this instance.

Comment: Weird though, Ruby should be able to work with field names like `emails[]=foo&emails[]=bar`, etc. I'm guessing that server component is not under your control?

Comment: Very weird. We're trying work out if it is at our end or if it's a Ruby, Associations, PG edge case. Correct, it's not under my control!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code is changing `emailObj` from an object to a string on each iteration of the loop, instead of amending a property of the object itself. Also note that you can use the `.` style selector to match elements by their class.

To achieve what you require, you can use `map()` to create an array from a group of elements in a jQuery object. You can then assign this to the required property of your `emailObj` object. For example:

```
var emailObj = {};
emailObj.emails = $("input.authority-email").map(function () {
    return this.value;
});
console.log(emailObj.emails); // = [ 'a@a.com', 'b@b.com', ... ]
```

To update the object in 'real-time', hook to the `change` and `keyup` events of the inputs themselves:

```
var emailObj = {};
$("input.authority-email").on('change keyup', function() {
    emailObj.emails = $("input.authority-email").map(function () {
        return this.value;
    });
    console.log(emailObj.emails); // = [ 'a@a.com', 'b@b.com', ... ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful answer Rory. Will this change the `emailObj` as the inputs change without having to refresh the page? I need to build an array from it and pass it to a hidden field before it's passed to the database?

Comment: No, this will only build the array once. The best place to do it would be on the `submit()` event of your form. If you want to update it as the user types, hook to the `change` *and* `keyup` events of the individual `input` elements.

Comment: @ThomasTaylor Why do you need to store this into a hidden input field? If you're going to submit the form anyway those input fields would get submitted anyway.

Comment: @Ja͢ck the data is going into a single rails array form which requires it to be in specific format.

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan on `submit()` makes more sense then doing it in real-time. However, my question clearly asks how the emailObj can be changed in real-time. I'm not sure if I should mark this as right as it would be misleading to other users.

Comment: @ThomasTaylor I updated my answer to include a real-time implementation.